# $< \infty$ versus $< +\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, soft-question, terminology, infinity

In several books and articles (mainly those in Functional Analysis and Differential Geometry), when the authors wish to say a certain quantity or function is finite they write $< + \infty$ as opposed to just $ < \infty$.

I know the term “finite” could refer to both the negative and positive bounds but if the authors are already writing in mathematical notation, why insist on adding a plus sign? Is $< \infty$ somehow ambiguous?

Comment: Different authors use different notations

Comment: Unary $+$ is a no-op. There is no ambiguity just a desire to to highlight something. Who cares?

Comment: What sources in functional analysis and differential geometry are you finding that do this? The peculiarities of one or two authors is not worth all the fuss.

Comment: @TedShifrin For example the book on "Lectures on nonsmooth differential geometry" by Gigli and Pasqualetto do this frequently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, kind of.

$\infty$ could be considered a commoner for $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.
To make it sure that something like the order of a group or the cardinality of a set is finite, which cannot in any case be negative, it is reasonable to emphasize it using the symbol $<+\infty$.

Having said it, the fact remains that the usage is not universal.

Comment: F.A.Mala, what do you mean when you write “$\infty$ could be considered a commoner for $+\infty$ and $-\infty\,?$

Comment: @Angelo In contexts where one needs no distinction between these two infinities.

Comment: @Angelo, presumably because in some contexts, $\infty$ represents the point at $\infty$, that is the one point compactification. On the reals, this forces the real line to bend around, effectively associating $+\infty$ with $-\infty$.

Comment: F.A.Mala, you mean that $\infty$ in some contexts could be considered a short form for $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, that is, it would represent the two infinities simultaneously, at the same time. Do you mean it?

Comment: As @CameronWilliams comments... and, indeed, doing complex analysis, the one-point compactification is what is relevant for limiting values of complex numbers (as opposed to inequalities).

Comment: @Angelo, yes, I do.

Comment: People put all sorts of things in print, but that is just awful. In authors that I respect, the closest to what you are saying that I have seen is denoting $x\to\infty$ for $|x|\to +\infty$. Certainly never $x<\infty$ to mean both $-\infty<x <+\infty$. I have indeed seen students and teachers doing that. The $\infty$ of the one-point compactification of the reals wouldn't go in an inequality.

Comment: "To make it sure that something like the order of a group or the cardinality of a set is finite, which cannot in any case be negative, it is reasonable to emphasize it using the symbol <+∞." - I don't understand this part of the answer.

Comment: The word "commoner" doesn't make sense here. What do you mean by it?